# Could chat rooms be enhanced to enable the typing of formatted code

Tags: feature-request, chat, code-formatting

At the moment it seems impossible to show somone, in a chat, a simple example of a few lines of code, because you can't indent it properly.

Since we're all here to discuss code, for the most part, this seems to be rather a problem.

The issue I'm referring to can be seen by typing

```
`test`
`   indented test`
```

in a chat room.

The result is

```
test
`  indented test`
```

I can see that blocks of code would be discouraged, by not allowing multiline code blocks to be recognised, but a single indented line seems really necessary...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. Indent each line of a message by 4 spaces (or use the fixed font button) and it will appear as a code block.

Comment: Leading spaces are removed in chat room messages.  What fixed font button are you referring to?

Comment: Oh, that's wierd.  NOW it works!

Comment: Ah - now I see what I was doing wrong.     Thanks for the tip about the fixed font button, which only appears if you hit shift-enter in the chat box dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1:** Copy-paste in code (or type it out with shift-enter):

[image: Code stuff]

**Step 2:** Click the 'Fixed Font' button and it will all be indented another 4 spaces.

**Step 3:**

[image: Ta-da!]

**Step 4:** ???

**Step 5:** Profit

Answer (score 1):

This is already catered for, as @Doorknob pointed out.

The trick is that you need to hit shift-enter to get multiline in the chat entry dialog, and then hit the fixed-font button.

Or - you can *not* mark you code as code by using backticks, and enter the spaces manually line by line, but then you get double spaced lines in the chat transcript.

Other non-obvious magic is (again, as @Doorknob pointed out) that if you indent by 4 spaces, this is taken to mean "this is code", at zero indendation.   Another 4 spaces gives one level of indentation etc.

All good stuff to know :)